# Add line break for each item in list,items were found by using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find all the photo links in a website, and I use BeautifulSoup for it.
Here are my codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "http://cupp.cyberport.hk/zh_TW/front_programmes/index"
webpage = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(webpage.content, "html.parser")
images = []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
   images.append(img.get('src'))
   with open("photo_links.txt", "w") as text_file:
      text_file.write(str(images))
```

And the results are

```
['https://www.cyberport.hk/images/logo.jpg','https://www.cyberport.hk/img/weather_icon/black/54.png','https://www.cyberport.hk/images/facebook.jpg', 'https://www.cyberport.hk/images/twitter.jpg','https://www.cyberport.hk/images/linkin.jpg', 'http://cupp.cyberport.hk/files/general_content/upload/12/hkcityu_logo.jpg','http://cupp.cyberport.hk/files/general_content/upload/13/hkbu_logo.jpg']
```

All items in the list were printed in one single line in txt file.

I want each item to be separated with "\n"

like this

```
['https://www.cyberport.hk/images/logo.jpg',
'https://www.cyberport.hk/img/weather_icon/black/54.png',
'https://www.cyberport.hk/images/facebook.jpg', 
'https://www.cyberport.hk/images/twitter.jpg',
'https://www.cyberport.hk/images/linkin.jpg', 
'http://cupp.cyberport.hk/files/general_content/upload/12/hkcityu_logo.jpg',
'http://cupp.cyberport.hk/files/general_content/upload/13/hkbu_logo.jpg']
```

How can I modify the code so that I can get my preferred results?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the square brackets in your output?

Comment: Yes, I want all [] '' , to be kept in the output text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "http://cupp.cyberport.hk/zh_TW/front_programmes/index"
webpage = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(webpage.content, "html.parser")
images = []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
   images.append(img.get('src'))

url_list = '",\n"'.join(images)
with open("../test_files/photo_links.txt", "w") as text_file:
   text_file.write(f'"{url_list}",')
```

`'\n'.join(images)` creates a string of the items in `images` joined by `\n`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! However is there a way that I can keep the '' outside the link and the comma at the end of each line?

Answer (score 0):

could you try below solution?

amend the below code

```
text_file.write(str(images))
```

to the below code

```
text_file.write(str(images)+'\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it still has the same results, no line break.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using string formatting. Just inject concatenated list elements with `',\n'` between 2 square brackets:

```
text_file.write(f"[{',\n'.join(images)}]")
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: @E.Zeytinci I've updated my solution with a small explanation. Thank you for your comment!